# System.ArgumentException: 'Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.' when loading the form

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to load a form with a Combobox, I was modularising the code and messed up something and this problem pops up now. Any help much appreciated.

> System.ArgumentException: 'Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.'

This is my code

```
  Private Sub FillBookingDataCombo()
    Dim dt = GetBookingData()
    cmbRoomType.Items.Clear()


    cmbRoomType.DisplayMember = "fname"
    cmbRoomType.ValueMember = "BookingID"
    cmbRoomType.DataSource = dt
End Sub
 Public Function GetBookingData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Using con1 As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString),
        cmd As New SQLiteCommand("Select booking.BookingID, customers.fname FROM booking inner join customers ON booking.bcustomerid = customers.customerid ", con1)
        con1.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: Set `cmbRoomType.DataSource = Nothing` instead of clearing the Items collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the error appears on the line `cmbRoomType.Items.Clear()`.  If I am correct, just delete that line.

That is used for the mode where you do not use a DataTable with the combo, but instead add items to the combo.

When using a DataTable, the combo will display whatever is in the DataTable, and you do not add or remove items via the combo itself.

Comment: that works but now i get this error message `Cannot bind to the new value member.
Parameter name: value`

Comment: You need to assign the datasource before the valuemember. Put the line `cmbRoomType.DataSource = dt` before the `.DisplayMember` and `.ValueMember` assignments.

Comment: I use a slightly different type of combo box more often, so I don't know if this applies to yours - but they sometimes have a problem if you assign the DataSource too soon. If your methods are called from a constructor, try moving them to a parent form load event.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I realized where I went wrong. I had two subprocedures assigning to the same Combobox

Comment: NP. Feel free to mark the checkbox to accept my answer if it helped :)

Comment: Nope, `DisplayMember` should be set **before** the DataSource, otherwise you always bind the data source twice, or more times. Just set the DataSource to null (`Nothing`) before setting a new one, so it will clean up the buffers.